# Issues with form submit and preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been searching for a few hours trying to find a solution to the issue I'm having. I have an external jQuery page to submit form data to a server. I've tried using event.preventDefault, and return false; but neither of these seem to work. In addition if I add an alert to the first line of the function it does not appear.

Here is the jQuery code and HTML code for the formL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//----------------------------------------------------Sign up------------------------------------------------------------------
$('#signup-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    alert("This is working");
    event.preventDefault();

    var subData = {
        'username'      : $('suser').val(),
        'password'      : $('spass').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', //define the HTTP verb we want to use
        url         : 'createUser.php', // url where we want to post
        data        : subData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json' //what type of data we expect back from the     server
        })
    });
});


<form id="signup-form" action="createUser.php" method="post">
        <input class="username" id="suser" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required><br>
        <input class="password" id="spass" type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
        <input class="password" id="spassconf" type="text" name="password-confirm" placeholder="confirm password" required><br>
        <input id="signup-submit" type="submit" value="Signup">
</form>
```

I've tried using .submit( and .on('submit',  thought neither seem to work. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the event not being recognized but I couldn't find a solution that works for me. I'm using chrome if that helps.

If you need any of the other code I'll be happy to supply it.

Edit: PHP code by request

```
<?php

//get form fields into php variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$serverName = "198.71.225.145";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Ironicism_database_project", "UID"=>"ironicism", "PWD"=>"Redhorsemagnet8*");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn===false) {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO ironicism.users (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";


$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false)
{
    echo "Data Could not be inserted.... working on that yo.<br />";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Comment: Delete this `action="createUser.php" method="post"`

Comment: **event** is a reserved keyword in JS. Stop using it as variable.

Comment: `event` is not reserved keyword. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: Existing code is working as expected in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/w5m1ha2e/) without making any change in code...

Comment: @Mr_Green Ups.. My bad.. Should be an identifier instead? According to [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) and my long past experience..

Comment: Put the script to the footer or just below this form
And delete the action tag and method tag in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have defined a form `action` and `method` attributes that are self sufficient to handle the for submit action. In this case your form submits and it may refresh the page thus your `event.preventDefault()` is not working.

Remove the form `action` and `method` attribute from the form and see the result.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
//----------------------------------------------------Sign up------------------------------------------------------------------
$('#signup-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    alert("This is working");
    event.preventDefault();

    var subData = {
        'username'      : $('suser').val(),
        'password'      : $('spass').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', //define the HTTP verb we want to use
        url         : 'createUser.php', // url where we want to post
        data        : subData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json' //what type of data we expect back from the     server
        })
    });
});


<form id="signup-form">
        <input class="username" id="suser" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required><br>
        <input class="password" id="spass" type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
        <input class="password" id="spassconf" type="text" name="password-confirm" placeholder="confirm password" required><br>
        <input id="signup-submit" type="submit" value="Signup">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tested the existing code before posting this answer ?

Comment: @Rayon Do you need to test it, Doesn't it seem to you like and obvious mistake. and by the way where would I get the php file to test. I wrote the answer learning from my experience with a similar problem

Comment: When OP says it does not work, give it a try once whether he is correct or not.. It will also make you realize the mistake OP is doing.. [__Here__](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/w5m1ha2e/) is the fiddle of what OP has shared and it is working fine.. What made you think it will not work! I am surprised...

Comment: @Rayon: OP was firing two form submit events and since it is async request how will one say with surity which request fires first. I will appreciate your response. Will help me further. And yes your fiddle does work correctly, I checked that.

Comment: _"OP was firing two form submit events"_ ? Where are they ? I have copied the same code OP had shared...

Comment: @Rayon As I said in my answer one from within the HTML as form action and one from the jquery he wrote.In your fiddle just remove all the jquery and still you can POST the form. Try and check that.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri – That is irrelevant.. `event.preventDefault()` will prevent form submission no matter what you write in any attribute...

Comment: @Ironicism Happy to Help! :)

Answer (score -1):

1) If you dont want to refresh page on submit click event, just change button type from submit to button:

```
<input id="signup-submit" type="button" value="Signup">
```

2) Remove action value from the Form tag

3) take button click event instead of submit event:

```
$('button').on('click', function(event) { // change it
    alert("This is working");
    event.preventDefault();

    var subData = {
        'username'      : $('suser').val(),
        'password'      : $('spass').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', //define the HTTP verb we want to use
        url         : 'createUser.php', // url where we want to post
        data        : subData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json' //what type of data we expect back from the     server
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh wow... I feel like an idiot that I didn't try that. Thank you very much for the prompt response. Once the timer is up I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Ironicism welcome... :) mark it correct if it solved problem